# Is there a way to diagnose this camera issue? Like some kind of crash dump or log? [unrooted Galaxy Note 9]

Tags: camera, crashes, logging, samsung-galaxy-note, crash-reports

After water damage, my phone camera had to be replaced.

The camera worked after replacement, for a day or so. Then it came up with a black screen (menus are there, just no image). A reboot fixed that for a day, but now it's back and rebooting (even to safe mode) doesn't help. It's been long enough that it's dry but I know there could be residual damage.

I'd just like confirm whether it's hardware or software. Is there a log that might provide a clue? And can I view it without root?

Comment: I would start using different camera apps. Of course they all use the camera interface provided by Android but at the Samsung camera app may use direct Samsung specific API or even directly access camera so other camera apps would be a first test.

Comment: @robert good thought. Looks like it's a hardware thing, two other apps get the same result. Disappointing because it doesn't seem like there's anything left to replace unless it's the entire board.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Sorry to hear about the situation, but perhaps [How can I view and examine the Android log?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/44325) may at least help in checking what happens when the camera apps run; do they return an exception (possibly software or OS issue) or nothing wrong (possibly hardware)?