# AntennaPod podcast app plays audio in personal profile, but not in work profile

Tags: work-profiles, android-14

I use [AntennaPod](https://antennapod.org/) for podcasts, and I have it installed in both my personal profile and my work profile. It's installed through [Island](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.island). Under my personal profile, the app works normally. Under my work profile, I can add podcasts, download episodes, etc., **but when I click the play button in the app, nothing happens.** No error, the app doesn't crash, but it simply doesn't play.

How can I debug this? Is this an issue with work profiles or with the app?

I'm using a Google Pixel 5a using Android 14 (the latest update from earlier in October 2023).

The log file is too long to paste here, so I put it on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/raw/z6ALYR92

Here are all the lines from the `adb logcat` that refer to AntennaPod:

```
11-01 16:33:04.047  1818  5594 I ImeTracker: de.danoeh.antennapod:d4a6fb4a: onRequestHide at ORIGIN_SERVER_HIDE_INPUT reason HIDE_SAME_WINDOW_FOCUSED_WITHOUT_EDITOR
11-01 16:33:04.048  1818  5594 I ImeTracker: de.danoeh.antennapod:d4a6fb4a: onCancelled at PHASE_SERVER_SHOULD_HIDE
11-01 16:33:04.081  6334  6334 I GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.onStartInput():1894 onStartInput(EditorInfo{EditorInfo{packageName=de.danoeh.antennapod, inputType=0, inputTypeString=NULL, enableLearning=false, autoCorrection=false, autoComplete=false, imeOptions=0, privateImeOptions=null, actionName=UNSPECIFIED, actionLabel=null, initialSelStart=-1, initialSelEnd=-1, initialCapsMode=0, label=null, fieldId=0, fieldName=null, extras=null, hintText=null, hintLocales=[]}}, false)
11-01 16:33:08.006  1818  5594 D ConnectivityService: requestNetwork for uid/pid:1010282/26142 activeRequest: null callbackRequest: 6894 [NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6895, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]] callback flags: 0 order: 2147483647
11-01 16:33:08.012  1818  2399 D WifiNetworkFactory: got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6895, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
11-01 16:33:08.012  1818  2399 D UntrustedWifiNetworkFactory: got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6895, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
11-01 16:33:08.013  1818  2399 D OemPaidWifiNetworkFactory: got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6895, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
11-01 16:33:08.013  1818  2399 D MultiInternetWifiNetworkFactory: got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6895, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
11-01 16:33:08.040  1818  2165 V WindowManager:     info={id=2227 t=CLOSE f=0x0 trk=0 r=[0@Point(0, 0)] c=[{null m=CLOSE f=FILLS_TASK leash=Surface(name=ActivityRecord{e7c9c09 u10 de.danoeh.antennapod/.activity.PreferenceActivity)/@0x7a4f0d4 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) d=0},{null m=TO_FRONT f=FILLS_TASK leash=Surface(name=ActivityRecord{b6d2089 u10 de.danoeh.antennapod/.activity.MainActivity)/@0x2cb57c1 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) d=0}]}
11-01 16:33:08.042  2503  2535 V WindowManagerShell: onTransitionReady android.os.BinderProxy@9e294e7: {id=2227 t=CLOSE f=0x0 trk=0 r=[0@Point(0, 0)] c=[{null m=CLOSE f=FILLS_TASK leash=Surface(name=ActivityRecord{e7c9c09 u10 de.danoeh.antennapod/.activity.PreferenceActivity)/@0x81f894 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) d=0},{null m=TO_FRONT f=FILLS_TASK leash=Surface(name=ActivityRecord{b6d2089 u10 de.danoeh.antennapod/.activity.MainActivity)/@0x78c1f3d sb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) d=0}]}
11-01 16:33:08.046  2503  2535 V WindowManagerShell: Transition doesn't have explicit remote, search filters for match for {id=2227 t=CLOSE f=0x0 trk=0 r=[0@Point(0, 0)] c=[{null m=CLOSE f=FILLS_TASK leash=Surface(name=ActivityRecord{e7c9c09 u10 de.danoeh.antennapod/.activity.PreferenceActivity)/@0x81f894 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) d=0},{null m=TO_FRONT f=FILLS_TASK leash=Surface(name=ActivityRecord{b6d2089 u10 de.danoeh.antennapod/.activity.MainActivity)/@0x78c1f3d sb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) d=0}]}
11-01 16:33:08.047  2503  2535 V WindowManagerShell: start default transition animation, info = {id=2227 t=CLOSE f=0x0 trk=0 r=[0@Point(0, 0)] c=[{null m=CLOSE f=FILLS_TASK leash=Surface(name=ActivityRecord{e7c9c09 u10 de.danoeh.antennapod/.activity.PreferenceActivity)/@0x81f894 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) d=0},{null m=TO_FRONT f=FILLS_TASK leash=Surface(name=ActivityRecord{b6d2089 u10 de.danoeh.antennapod/.activity.MainActivity)/@0x78c1f3d sb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) d=0}]}
11-01 16:33:08.093  1818  5594 I ImeTracker: de.danoeh.antennapod:5fe7ea68: onRequestHide at ORIGIN_SERVER_HIDE_INPUT reason HIDE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN_STATE
11-01 16:33:08.093  1818  5594 I ImeTracker: de.danoeh.antennapod:5fe7ea68: onCancelled at PHASE_SERVER_SHOULD_HIDE
11-01 16:33:08.095  6334  6334 I GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.onStartInput():1894 onStartInput(EditorInfo{EditorInfo{packageName=de.danoeh.antennapod, inputType=0, inputTypeString=NULL, enableLearning=false, autoCorrection=false, autoComplete=false, imeOptions=0, privateImeOptions=null, actionName=UNSPECIFIED, actionLabel=null, initialSelStart=-1, initialSelEnd=-1, initialCapsMode=0, label=null, fieldId=0, fieldName=null, extras=null, hintText=null, hintLocales=[]}}, false)
11-01 16:33:08.146  1818  4930 D CoreBackPreview: Window{81a163c u10 de.danoeh.antennapod/de.danoeh.antennapod.activity.PreferenceActivity}: Setting back callback null
11-01 16:33:08.148  1818  4930 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object '81a163c de.danoeh.antennapod/de.danoeh.antennapod.activity.PreferenceActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
11-01 16:33:10.019 26142 32065 D DBReader: getFeedItemList() called with: feed = [de.danoeh.antennapod.model.feed.Feed@2]
11-01 16:33:12.343 26142 26142 D NavDrawerFragment: onQueueChanged(de.danoeh.antennapod.event.QueueEvent@99da3f)
11-01 16:33:12.343 26142 26142 D ItemlistFragment: onEventMainThread() called with: event = [de.danoeh.antennapod.event.FeedItemEvent@d4ba6a]
11-01 16:33:12.343 26142 32066 D DBReader: getFeedItemList() called with: feed = [de.danoeh.antennapod.model.feed.Feed@2]
11-01 16:33:12.346 26142 32064 D DBReader: getFeedItemList() called with: feed = [de.danoeh.antennapod.model.feed.Feed@2]
11-01 16:33:12.358  1818  5594 D ConnectivityService: requestNetwork for uid/pid:1010282/26142 activeRequest: null callbackRequest: 6896 [NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6897, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]] callback flags: 0 order: 2147483647
11-01 16:33:12.364  1818  2399 D WifiNetworkFactory: got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6897, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
11-01 16:33:12.365  1818  2399 D UntrustedWifiNetworkFactory: got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6897, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
11-01 16:33:12.366  1818  2399 D OemPaidWifiNetworkFactory: got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6897, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
11-01 16:33:12.366  1818  2399 D MultiInternetWifiNetworkFactory: got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6897, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
11-01 16:33:12.427  1818  5594 I WifiService: acquireWifiLock uid=1010282 lockMode=1 packageName=de.danoeh.antennapod
11-01 16:33:15.249 26142 26248 D de.danoeh.antennapod.storage.database.PodDBAdapter@8cfdbfc: Updating existing Feed in db
11-01 16:33:15.254 26142 26142 D ItemlistFragment: onEventMainThread() called with: event = [de.danoeh.antennapod.event.FeedItemEvent@66fa285]
11-01 16:33:15.260 26142 26185 I WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=6996d088-a816-4f8d-b682-6be92f994439, tags={ episodeDownload, de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.download.EpisodeDownloadWorker, episodeUrl:http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/mediaselector/6/redir/version/2.0/mediaset/audio-nondrm-download/proto/http/vpid/p0ggrzc8.mp3, was_queued } ]
11-01 16:33:15.272  1818  4930 W JobScheduler: Job didn't exist in JobStore: 9c3bb71 #u10a282/37 de.danoeh.antennapod/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
11-01 16:33:33.290  1818  5056 I ActivityManager: Background started FGS: Allowed [callingPackage: de.danoeh.antennapod; callingUid: 1010282; uidState: TOP ; uidBFSL: [BFSL]; intent: Intent { cmp=de.danoeh.antennapod/.core.service.playback.PlaybackService (has extras) }; code:PROC_STATE_TOP; tempAllowListReason:<null>; targetSdkVersion:33; callerTargetSdkVersion:33; startForegroundCount:0; bindFromPackage:null: isBindService:false]
11-01 16:33:33.322  1818  5056 I MediaSessionStack: addSession to bottom of stack | record: de.danoeh.antennapod/PlaybackService (userId=10)
11-01 16:33:33.458  1818  2557 I MediaSessionStack: onPlaybackStateChanged - Pushing session to top | record: de.danoeh.antennapod/PlaybackService (userId=10)
11-01 16:33:33.463 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.QuickSettingsTileService$$ExternalSyntheticApiModelOutline0.m(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
11-01 16:33:33.463 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService$3.statusChanged(PlaybackService.java:840)
11-01 16:33:33.463 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.playback.base.PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.setPlayerStatus(PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.java:315)
11-01 16:33:33.463 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.playback.base.PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.setPlayerStatus(PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.java:327)
11-01 16:33:33.463 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP.playMediaObject(LocalPSMP.java:160)
11-01 16:33:33.463 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP.playMediaObject(LocalPSMP.java:113)
11-01 16:33:33.463 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.startPlaying(PlaybackService.java:729)
11-01 16:33:33.463 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.lambda$onStartCommand$6(PlaybackService.java:520)
11-01 16:33:33.463 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.$r8$lambda$mOCf9qqsskaQGmxsaI_m2ZmJO2w(PlaybackService.java:0)
11-01 16:33:33.463 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.accept(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
11-01 16:33:33.464 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.QuickSettingsTileService$$ExternalSyntheticApiModelOutline0.m(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
11-01 16:33:33.464 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService$3.statusChanged(PlaybackService.java:840)
11-01 16:33:33.464 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.playback.base.PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.setPlayerStatus(PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.java:315)
11-01 16:33:33.464 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.playback.base.PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.setPlayerStatus(PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.java:327)
11-01 16:33:33.464 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP.playMediaObject(LocalPSMP.java:160)
11-01 16:33:33.464 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP.playMediaObject(LocalPSMP.java:113)
11-01 16:33:33.464 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.startPlaying(PlaybackService.java:729)
11-01 16:33:33.464 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.lambda$onStartCommand$6(PlaybackService.java:520)
11-01 16:33:33.464 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.$r8$lambda$mOCf9qqsskaQGmxsaI_m2ZmJO2w(PlaybackService.java:0)
11-01 16:33:33.464 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.accept(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
11-01 16:33:33.469  1818  2557 I MediaSessionStack: removeSession | record: de.danoeh.antennapod/PlaybackService (userId=10)
11-01 16:33:33.472  1818  2557 I MediaFocusControl: abandonAudioFocus() from uid/pid 1010282/26142 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@d342ca7de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP$1@4fc1554
11-01 16:33:36.016  1818  2557 I ActivityManager: Background started FGS: Allowed [callingPackage: de.danoeh.antennapod; callingUid: 1010282; uidState: TOP ; uidBFSL: [BFSL]; intent: Intent { cmp=de.danoeh.antennapod/.core.service.playback.PlaybackService (has extras) }; code:PROC_STATE_TOP; tempAllowListReason:<null>; targetSdkVersion:33; callerTargetSdkVersion:33; startForegroundCount:0; bindFromPackage:null: isBindService:false]
11-01 16:33:36.045  1818  2557 I MediaSessionStack: addSession to bottom of stack | record: de.danoeh.antennapod/PlaybackService (userId=10)
11-01 16:33:36.050  1818  2557 W ActivityManager: Receiver with filter android.content.IntentFilter@1055f02 already registered for pid 26142, callerPackage is de.danoeh.antennapod
11-01 16:33:36.051  1818  2557 W ActivityManager: Receiver with filter android.content.IntentFilter@fc84013 already registered for pid 26142, callerPackage is de.danoeh.antennapod
11-01 16:33:36.054  1818  2557 W ActivityManager: Receiver with filter android.content.IntentFilter@58fcc49 already registered for pid 26142, callerPackage is de.danoeh.antennapod
11-01 16:33:36.054  1818  2557 W ActivityManager: Receiver with filter android.content.IntentFilter@7ee694e already registered for pid 26142, callerPackage is de.danoeh.antennapod
11-01 16:33:36.080  1818  2330 I MediaSessionStack: onPlaybackStateChanged - Pushing session to top | record: de.danoeh.antennapod/PlaybackService (userId=10)
11-01 16:33:36.080 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.QuickSettingsTileService$$ExternalSyntheticApiModelOutline0.m(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
11-01 16:33:36.080 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService$3.statusChanged(PlaybackService.java:840)
11-01 16:33:36.080 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.playback.base.PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.setPlayerStatus(PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.java:315)
11-01 16:33:36.080 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.playback.base.PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.setPlayerStatus(PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.java:327)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP.playMediaObject(LocalPSMP.java:160)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP.playMediaObject(LocalPSMP.java:113)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.startPlaying(PlaybackService.java:729)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.lambda$onStartCommand$6(PlaybackService.java:520)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.$r8$lambda$mOCf9qqsskaQGmxsaI_m2ZmJO2w(PlaybackService.java:0)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.accept(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.QuickSettingsTileService$$ExternalSyntheticApiModelOutline0.m(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService$3.statusChanged(PlaybackService.java:840)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.playback.base.PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.setPlayerStatus(PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.java:315)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.playback.base.PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.setPlayerStatus(PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.java:327)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP.playMediaObject(LocalPSMP.java:160)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP.playMediaObject(LocalPSMP.java:113)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.startPlaying(PlaybackService.java:729)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.lambda$onStartCommand$6(PlaybackService.java:520)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.$r8$lambda$mOCf9qqsskaQGmxsaI_m2ZmJO2w(PlaybackService.java:0)
11-01 16:33:36.081 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.accept(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
11-01 16:33:36.084  1818  2330 I MediaSessionStack: removeSession | record: de.danoeh.antennapod/PlaybackService (userId=10)
11-01 16:33:36.088  1818  2557 I MediaFocusControl: abandonAudioFocus() from uid/pid 1010282/26142 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@90527a2de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP$1@2916c33
11-01 16:33:36.177 26142 26142 W noeh.antennapod: Entry not found
11-01 16:33:36.322  1818  5056 W ProcessStats: Tracking association SourceState{cbd5141 de.danoeh.antennapod/1010282 BTop #281656} whose proc state 2 is better than process ProcessState{3a7f518 com.google.android.gms/1010182 pkg=com.google.android.gms} proc state 6 (20 skipped)
11-01 16:33:36.341  1818  2197 I ActivityManager: Start proc 32152:com.google.android.webview:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:0/u10i185 for  {de.danoeh.antennapod/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:0}
11-01 16:33:36.470 26142 32177 E chromium: [ERROR:simple_file_enumerator.cc(21)] opendir /data/user/10/de.danoeh.antennapod/cache/WebView/Default/HTTP Cache/Code Cache/wasm: No such file or directory (2)
11-01 16:33:36.528  1818  5594 D ConnectivityService: requestNetwork for uid/pid:1010282/26142 activeRequest: null callbackRequest: 6900 [NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6901, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]] callback flags: 0 order: 2147483647
11-01 16:33:36.534  1818  2399 D WifiNetworkFactory: got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6901, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
11-01 16:33:36.534  1818  2399 D UntrustedWifiNetworkFactory: got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6901, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
11-01 16:33:36.535  1818  2399 D OemPaidWifiNetworkFactory: got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6901, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
11-01 16:33:36.535  1818  2399 D MultiInternetWifiNetworkFactory: got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=6901, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 1010282 RequestorUid: 1010282 RequestorPkg: de.danoeh.antennapod UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]
11-01 16:33:38.493  1818  5594 I ActivityManager: Background started FGS: Allowed [callingPackage: de.danoeh.antennapod; callingUid: 1010282; uidState: TOP ; uidBFSL: [BFSL]; intent: Intent { cmp=de.danoeh.antennapod/.core.service.playback.PlaybackService (has extras) }; code:PROC_STATE_TOP; tempAllowListReason:<null>; targetSdkVersion:33; callerTargetSdkVersion:33; startForegroundCount:0; bindFromPackage:null: isBindService:false]
11-01 16:33:38.517  1818  5594 I MediaSessionStack: addSession to bottom of stack | record: de.danoeh.antennapod/PlaybackService (userId=10)
11-01 16:33:38.520  1818  5056 W ActivityManager: Receiver with filter android.content.IntentFilter@78bdea9 already registered for pid 26142, callerPackage is de.danoeh.antennapod
11-01 16:33:38.520  1818  5056 W ActivityManager: Receiver with filter android.content.IntentFilter@41b7c2e already registered for pid 26142, callerPackage is de.danoeh.antennapod
11-01 16:33:38.523  1818  5056 W ActivityManager: Receiver with filter android.content.IntentFilter@cf1b15c already registered for pid 26142, callerPackage is de.danoeh.antennapod
11-01 16:33:38.523  1818  5056 W ActivityManager: Receiver with filter android.content.IntentFilter@1abc65 already registered for pid 26142, callerPackage is de.danoeh.antennapod
11-01 16:33:38.569  1818  5056 I MediaSessionStack: onPlaybackStateChanged - Pushing session to top | record: de.danoeh.antennapod/PlaybackService (userId=10)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.QuickSettingsTileService$$ExternalSyntheticApiModelOutline0.m(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService$3.statusChanged(PlaybackService.java:840)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.playback.base.PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.setPlayerStatus(PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.java:315)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.playback.base.PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.setPlayerStatus(PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.java:327)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP.playMediaObject(LocalPSMP.java:160)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP.playMediaObject(LocalPSMP.java:113)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.startPlaying(PlaybackService.java:729)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.lambda$onStartCommand$6(PlaybackService.java:520)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.$r8$lambda$mOCf9qqsskaQGmxsaI_m2ZmJO2w(PlaybackService.java:0)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.accept(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.QuickSettingsTileService$$ExternalSyntheticApiModelOutline0.m(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService$3.statusChanged(PlaybackService.java:840)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.playback.base.PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.setPlayerStatus(PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.java:315)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.playback.base.PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.setPlayerStatus(PlaybackServiceMediaPlayer.java:327)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP.playMediaObject(LocalPSMP.java:160)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP.playMediaObject(LocalPSMP.java:113)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.startPlaying(PlaybackService.java:729)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.lambda$onStartCommand$6(PlaybackService.java:520)
11-01 16:33:38.571 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService.$r8$lambda$mOCf9qqsskaQGmxsaI_m2ZmJO2w(PlaybackService.java:0)
11-01 16:33:38.572 26142 26142 W System.err:    at de.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.PlaybackService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.accept(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
11-01 16:33:38.578  1818  5056 I MediaSessionStack: removeSession | record: de.danoeh.antennapod/PlaybackService (userId=10)
11-01 16:33:38.583  1818  5594 I MediaFocusControl: abandonAudioFocus() from uid/pid 1010282/26142 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@e28678fde.danoeh.antennapod.core.service.playback.LocalPSMP$1@e5bda1c
```

---

EDIT: I updated the post with a link to the Island app that I used to enable the work profile and install applications in it, as well as the log file from running `adb logcat` and then pressing play within AntennaPod in the work profile.

Comment: Unclear what is meant by "installed through Island" (i.e. link to app/which profile is running). Getting logs is best. If you are allowed `developer options` / `adb`, follow: [How can I view and examine the Android log?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/157594/3573)

Comment: Does the app play the podcast inside it, or does it depend on an external player?

Comment: @AndrewT. I'm not sure. There is no option that I can find within the app to use an external player, so I'm assuming it's an internal player.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thank you for the tips. I updated the question with a link to the Island app that I used, as well as the log file generated by `adb logcat` while I press play within the AntennaPod app in the work profile.

Comment: @MichaelA Better to add to the question the logcat to what seems important perhaps one with normal profile and one with work profile of attempting to play) as I can't access your pastebin link. As the `Island` app has `DEVICE_ADMIN` rights I would also check admin app settings to see if there is a media block of some kind.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks. I can come back to this later, but for now I updated the question with all lines from the log that have "AntennaPod" in them.

Comment: I have a feeling the problem is related to ExoPlayer (Android built-in media player) around 16:33:33, particularly `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: User 10 is not the current user.` However, I still can't find the solution to it.