# WiFi doesn't want to turn on on Xiaomi Mi 10i

Tags: wi-fi, xiaomi

My Xiaomi Mi 10i was glitching and I sent it for repair, but unfortunately, after repair, the WiFi doesn't want to turn on (it just turns off from the settings toggle and doesn't turn on from notifications).

After a few days, it automatically fixed itself, but then I had it factory reinstalled (because I thought it would have spyware from the repair shop) and now it doesn't work anymore.

Bluetooth and cellular data have no problem in working.

I wish someone could help me with this.

Comment: Do you mean factory reset, or did you do something more?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. I'm afraid the problem is actually with the physical hardware component and thus there's nothing this community can do. Perhaps [viewing the logcat](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/44325) and checking if there are consistent errors when toggling the WiFi on may help in debugging the issue further. Otherwise, flashing the stock ROM might be the last choice.